# Unable to spin dockerized cassandra cluster on Mesosphere DC/OS

Tags: docker, cassandra, marathon, dcos

Can anyone have some idea to create a Cassandra cluster on Mesosphere DC/OS using Docker?

The issue is that Cassandra containers keep getting started after every few seconds.

It seems that Marathon is failing to get the health status of the newly created containers because it keeps creating new ones continuously. In DC/OS GUI service debug, it shows

```
State: TASK_FAILED
Message: Container terminated with signal Broken pipe
```

While checking on the machine, the containers are up and running and also new containers are getting creating repeatedly in every minute or two.

Why marathon doesn't get the correct response from the container that it has started successfully so that it can stop creating a new one?

I am sharing my current JSON configuration for the service. 
Cassandra.json

```
{
 "id": "/cassandra",
 "acceptedResourceRoles": [
   "*"
 ],
 "backoffFactor": 1.15,
 "backoffSeconds": 1,
 "container": {
   "portMappings": [
     {
       "containerPort": 8000,
       "hostPort": 0,
       "protocol": "tcp",
       "servicePort": 10003,
       "name": "main"
     }
   ],
   "type": "DOCKER",
   "volumes": [],
   "docker": {
     "image": "cassandra:3.9",
     "forcePullImage": false,
     "privileged": false,
     "parameters": []
   }
 },
 "cpus": 3,
 "disk": 10000,
 "instances": 1,
 "maxLaunchDelaySeconds": 300,
 "mem": 6000,
 "gpus": 0,
 "networks": [
   {
     "mode": "container/bridge"
   }
 ],
 "requirePorts": false,
 "upgradeStrategy": {
   "maximumOverCapacity": 1,
   "minimumHealthCapacity": 1
 },
 "killSelection": "YOUNGEST_FIRST",
 "unreachableStrategy": {
   "inactiveAfterSeconds": 0,
   "expungeAfterSeconds": 0
 },
 "fetch": [],
 "constraints": []
}
```

```
DC/OS open source version 1.13
Marathon Version 1.8.194
```

Please help if anyone have some idea what's going on? I can share further details if needed.